# Multi module Maven Project dependency issue?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2, artifactory

I have a multi module project where **common-project** is depend on another **3rdparty** project and below is the `pom.xml` of **common-project**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

     <groupId>com.tri.iss.pet.common</groupId>     
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>common-um-entities</artifactId>
    <name>common-um-entities</name>
    <description>Common UM Entities</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tri.iss.pet.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>3rdparty</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you clearly check i have added dependency in pom.xml file but check below image its saying jar missing

[image]

Can someone tell me why only project dependency not able to load while other dependency which coming from Artifactory working fine ?

**Note:-** Dont be confuse from project name .

Comment: Can you supply the _complete_ message? Or even better: the relevant parts of an output of a `mvn` build?

Comment: The given can't be part of a multi module build cause it does not contain a parent relation.